# Update query in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using adapter in zend framework 2. My code is for mysql update query which is not working, can any one suggest me. Array result is ok but its not display in query. Just shows update tablename set.

I have tried all suggestions of SO and also from Google, but I am failed to solve that problem.

Code is here:

```
public function updatebhkdetail($bhkupdate)
{
    $WHERE = 'project_id='.$bhkupdate['project_id'];
    $sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
    $update1bhk = $sql->update('tablename', array($bhkupdate), $WHERE);
    $statementUpdate = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($update1bhk);
    $sectorName = $this->adapter->query($statementUpdate,
                         \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not to familiar with getSqlStringForSqlObject. But this should work:

```
$sql    = new Sql( $this->adapter );
$update = $sql->update();
$update->table( <yourTableName> );
$update->set( $keyValues );
$update->where( array( 'project_id' => $bhkupdate['project_id'] ) );

$statement  = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject( $update );
$results    = $statement->execute();
```

Comment: @peter Thanks a lot, I was fighting from last 40hours with this

Comment: I'd only add that if you need a prepared statement, it's better to use `where(['yourColumn = ?' => $yourVariable])`